# Unable to access ajax response property directly although it's there

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have the following JSON string returned from json_encode function of PHP 5.3.10 to jQuery 1.9.1

```
{
   "messsages":{
      "error":["API_CONTROLLER.INVALID_LOGIN_PASSWORD"],
      "warning":[],
      "notice":[],
      "success":[]
   },
   "result":false
}
```

The jQuery code:

```
$.ajax(targetURL, {
   type: method,
   data: params,
   dataType: "json",
   success: function(resp){
      console.log(resp); //Shows object with all vars correctly displayed

      //The for loop also outputs all keys and values correctly
      for(var i in resp){
         console.log("I: "+i);
         console.log("RESP: ");
         console.log(resp[i]);
      }

      console.log("DIRECT ACCESS");
      console.log(resp.messages); //WHY undefined?
      //console.log(resp.messages[error]); //undefined
      //console.log(resp.messages[error][0]); //undefined
      //console.log(resp.messages.error); //undefined
      //console.log(resp.messages.length); //Just trying => undefined
      console.log(resp.result); //this works!
      //console.log(resp[messages]); //Just trying => undefined
   }
});
```

How can I access messages?

The first console.log and loop shows that messages are present and also messages.error, messages.notice, etc... exist. But how can I access them? Is this kind of jQuery error?

Comment: lol me **sss** ages in json

Comment: Please don't put [solved] in the title. Accepting an answer means the problem is solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have three 's' in the name of messages var of your response. So it works while in the loop, but fails when you trying to access unexisting 'messages'.

Comment: Jesus...thanks. I was looking with 2 other people 1 hour at this code -.-

Answer (score 1):

Fix the typo first (**messsages**) then you can rewrite your code a bit :)

And **please** use [JavaScript Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts-breakpoints) in Google Chrome.

```
{
   "messages":{
      "error":["API_CONTROLLER.INVALID_LOGIN_PASSWORD"],
      "warning":[],
      "notice":[],
      "success":[]
   },
   "result":false
}

The jQuery code:

var performLogin = function(){
 return $.getJSON(targetURL, params).done(function(response){

      // TODO - do something with response

      console.log(response.messages);
      console.log(response.messages[error]);
      console.log(response.messages[error][0]);
      console.log(response.messages.error);
      console.log(response.messages.length);
      console.log(response.result);
      console.log(response[messages]);
   });
}
```